# repeated css background with a top padding

Tags: html, css

How can I add a repeated css background with an padding/space on top.

Here is my HTML Structure.

```
<div class="flare">
    <div class="clouds">
    <div class="clouds_bottom">

        <div class="header">
            contents
        </div>

        <div class="content_body_wrapper">
            contents
        </div>

        <div class="footer">
            contents
        </div>

    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and my css code that is not working.

```
.clouds_bottom {
    background: url('../img/clouds_bottom_bg.png') repeat left 250px;
}
```

Comment: Space on top once or on each row?

Comment: I just need space of 250px on top without any background, but I does not mean a top padding on body.

Comment: this is dependent on your site structure can you post the html of the class being used?

Comment: I have updated the post with my HTML structure.

Comment: Hard to guess but I would try margin-top: 250px on .clouds_bottom

Comment: well, I doesn't mean without any content. I just need 250px space without any background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cheating is allowed with CSS. Instead of placing you background 100% away from top cover it with another div with original background [color].

html:

```
<html>
<body>
    <div id="cheated_background">
    </div>
    <div id="body">
        content
    </div>
</body>
<html>​
```

css:

```
body {
    background: lightblue; /* your clouds :) */
}
#cheated_background {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    background: white;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
}
#body {
    position: relative;
}
```

Check out [live example](http://jsfiddle.net/seler/T6ME5/).

Answer (score 0):

Try using `repeat-x` instead of `repeat`? If it is repeated vertically, you will not be able to see the margin created by the background-position.

Edit to comment: If you need the repeat in both directions, what I could think of is a three-layer structure. You would need a container div with `position:relative` into which you could put three divs having `position:absolute`. The bottom one would have the repeated background picture, the middle one would be white and cover the top portion of the bottom one only, the top one would contain your actual content.

Comment: the problem is that I need the background to be repeated on both x and y position.